# How to theme a menu in drupal 7 with this html

Tags: theming

```
  <ul id="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>Home<br/><span class="SousTitle">The card of flight</span></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="list_news.html">News<br/><span class="SousTitle">The actual & promo</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="list_compagnie.html">Compagnies<br/><span class="SousTitle">More details</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="list_airport.html">Airports<br/><span class="SousTitle">Prepare your travel</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="forum.html">Forum<br/><span class="SousTitle">The community</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: What about [theme_menu_link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) is a problem? Also, possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317462/drupal-override-custom-menu-template but that's on another Stack, so not eligible for flagging.

Answer (score 1):

Use `theme_menu_tree()` theme function overrides

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7

Copy the contents of 'Code' on these pages to your theme's template.php and change the 'theme' in the function names to the name of your theme, for example:

```
function yourcustomtheme_menu_tree($variables) {
  return '<ul class="menu">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Make the changes to the HTML tags, save the template.php and clear caches.

Also if you just want to customize HTML for a specific menu, you can name your functions like this: `THEMENAME_menu_tree__MENU_NAME()`